# How to include user created by CreateUserWisard control to some role in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want the following behavior: 
When CreateUserWisard control in ASP.NET is called, add the created user by this control to 'Admin' role.

How can i do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add event listener:

```
        <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" 
          OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser">
          <WizardSteps>
            <asp:CreateUserWizardStep runat="server" Title="Yeni admin yarat" />
            <asp:CompleteWizardStep runat="server" Title="Tamamla" />
          </WizardSteps>
        </asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

And this is in your codebehind:

```
protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Roles.AddUserToRole(CreateUserWizard1.UserName, "Admin");
}
```